Verify the sequence of Time in JavaScript Selenium
I have a list of time as folllowing,
'a day ago,
10 days ago,
3 months ago,
6 months ago'.
How to verify that these dates are ascending? in javascript Selenium
I cant think of trying anything, I have some ideas for dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. But this Text format of the time made me confused.

There are many approaches you could elaborate and they range from very simple to more advanced.
A simple solution
Here a very simple variant, which assumes you will always have three parts in your time string so the pattern stays the same, namely
"<quantity token> <time span token> ago" 

The idea is then pretty simple

Split time string into individual tokens
Convert each token into a meaningful representation (a qunatitative measurement) i. e. a number for the <quantity token> or the number of milliseconds for the <time span token>
Multiply number * number of milliseconds to obtain how many milliseconds ago the event happened. Do this for every input time string and you'll get an array filled with number of millisecond ago values
Now you just have to ensure number of milliseconds is sorted in ascending order


I've added a few more possible tokens, not present in your input to show that you could easily extend this to other tokens.



const times = ["a day ago", "10 days ago", "3 months ago", "6 months ago"];
/tests?/.test("a day ago");
const termsOfQuanity = {
  a: 1,
  an: 1,
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  four: 4,
  five: 5,
  six: 6,
  seven: 7,
  eight: 8,
  nine: 9,
  ten: 10,
};

const milliSecondsPerTimeSpan = {
  seconds: 1000,
  minutes: 60000,
  hours: 3600000,
  days: 86400000,
  weeks: 604800000,
  months: 2629800000,
  years: 31557600000,
};
const timeSpans = {
  second: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.seconds,
  seconds: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.seconds,
  "second(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.seconds,
  minute: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.minutes,
  minutes: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.minutes,
  "minute(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.minutes,
  hour: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.hours,
  hours: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.hours,
  "hour(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.hours,
  day: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.days,
  days: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.days,
  "day(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.days,
  week: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.weeks,
  weeks: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.weeks,
  "week(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.weeks,
  month: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.months,
  months: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.months,
  "month(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.months,
  year: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.years,
  years: milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.years,
  "year(s)": milliSecondsPerTimeSpan.years,
};

function convertTimeStringToNumberOfMillisecondsAgo(timeString) {
  const [quantityToken, timeSpanToken, _] = timeString.split(" ");
  const quantity = convertQuantityTokenToNumber(quantityToken);
  const timeSpan = convertTimeSpanTokenToMilliseconds(timeSpanToken, quantity);
  return timeSpan * quantity;
}

function convertQuantityTokenToNumber(termOfQuantity) {
  const possibleNumberQuantity = parseInt(termOfQuantity);
  if (isNaN(possibleNumberQuantity)) {
    return termsOfQuanity[termOfQuantity];
  }
  return possibleNumberQuantity;
}

function convertTimeSpanTokenToMilliseconds(timeSpan) {
  return timeSpans[timeSpan];
}

const isSortedCorrectly = times
  .map(convertTimeStringToNumberOfMillisecondsAgo)
  .every((time, index, array) => index === 0 || array[index - 1] <= time);

console.log(`Is sorted correctly? ${isSortedCorrectly}`);



General remarks on a solution:

Steps 3 and 4 are straightforward and will be part of pretty much every solution for the problem.
Steps 1 (assuming you don't always have three tokens) and 2 are the more challenging steps for this problem and here is where you can code much more complex solutions

Possible improvements/ alternative solutions

You could check for number of tokens and then do some processing based on the number of token

E.g. if it's only one token: check for strings like today, yesterday etc.
If you have multiple tokens you could just via trial and error check to see whether you can parse a quantity token, if not, try to parse it as time span token and see if that gives you a meaningful resul. Of course this could introduce errors


Instead of using lookups in an JS object you could also use (complex) RegEx to distinguish certain (more complex) time span tokens and allow different casing like e.g. /days?/i.test(timeSpanToken)
You could use some AI model which can extract a value in milliseconds for a given string. This is probably the only variant which can also deal with completely unexpected time strings that you did not anticipate up-front.
You can also combine these approaches and maybe start with the simple version which catches most and only if the simple version cannot parse a string pass it on to one of the advanced versions with AI etc. to keep your effort (and cost for AI service etc.) low.

As always with natural language processing, there is probably no 100% safe method to be able to parse any string, but especially with AI you can probably get very close to 100%. For the most part I would assume a simple solution will do as I am assuming the time strings are also machine generated and displayed on some web-site and therefore generated with some simple pattern/ rule. So once you know the pattern you should be good. Of course you should have some monitoring notifying you if you can't process certain patterns, so that you notice right away when patterns change and can make appropriate adjustments.
Why there might not always be a definite answer
There might be some unquantified terms like few, a couple etc. as in a few minutes ago, a couple hours ago used so how do you compare that? What's bigger/ smaller? A couple or a few?
